# Overlay youtube embed with still image, along with embedding plugin in WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, youtube

I'm currently developing a website and custom theme in WordPress. On some of the Pages, a YouTube video will be embedded within the Page. To make it easy to update, I've used a plugin for embedding YouTube videos so when the user pastes the video URL, it embeds automatically.

The embed results in the following HTML code:

```
<div class="fluid-width-video-wrapper" style="padding-top: 56.25%;">
<iframe id="_ytid_72976" class="__youtube_prefs__" frameborder="0" mozallowfullscreen="" webkitallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen="" type="text/html" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/fNKwb6dvNTE?enablejsapi=1&autoplay=0&cc_load_policy=0&iv_load_policy=3&loop=0&modestbranding=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&playsinline=0&autohide=1&theme=dark&color=red&wmode=opaque&vq=&controls=2&">
</div>
```

Now, I'd like to combine this with a custom thumbnail. So basically adding an image and when the image is clicked, it will be replaced with the embed with jQuery, and the video will autoplay after being replaced. Preferably with by adding an image into a div or something, because I don't want the user to have to alter the CSS or a script each time a new Page is added.

I've seen several similar questions but I couldn't quite figure out how to make it work with this plugin.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you are trying to do here is not going to work for iPhones and iPads as they don't allow you to do autoplay. Just so you know.